# Defining footnote location with Kramdown/Jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I have a Jekyll blog that runs on kramdown 1.10, and I have tried to change the location of my footnote list to no avail. This is intended to go on a github-pages site, but doesn't work locally either.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/106), there is a way to add a footnote location elsewhere in your documents using Kramdown by defining a custom identifier that maps to a DOM object in your post.

Particularly I have added this to my `_config.yml`

```
kramdown:
  footnote_location: 'my_footnotes'
```

and tried all of these variations atthe desired location in my layout:

`<ol id="my_footnotes" class="my_footnotes"></ol>`

`<div id="my_footnotes" class="my_footnotes"></div>`

```
<div id="my_footnotes" class="my_footnotes">
   <ol id="my_footnotes" class="my_footnotes"></ol>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to generate footnotes in a specific location?

Answer (score 4):

In the issue you reference, they talk about the [implementation commit](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/8efa9c30c45014442970d5976dd0e0005682edf3/test/testcases/span/04_footnote/placement.text).

The interesting par is the [test file for footnote placement](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/8efa9c30c45014442970d5976dd0e0005682edf3/test/testcases/span/04_footnote/placement.html).

This is how to place your footnotes somewhere else than at the end of your page.

```
* footnotes will be placed here. This line is necessary
{:footnotes}
```